# Why does "Can not locate Debconf / Log.pm in @INC" issue? I just modified /usr/bin/perl into the perl that I installed

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apt-get

The system is Ubuntu. There is a perl in /usr/bin/, and is version is 5.18.2.
In this state, I tried to install many software by "sudo apt-get install **" and it was OK.

But a few days before, I installed a new perl in an other 
directory(/share/Software/perl-5.26.0/bin/perl). And I remove the original perl then link the new perl to /use/bin/. The commands are:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/old/; (the old/ directory was make before)
sudo ln -s /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/bin/perl /usr/bin/perl
```

After that, I got the error informations when I install system software by apt-get. The error likes below:

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (Can't locate Debconf/Log.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Debconf::Log module) (@INC contains: /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0/x86_64-linux /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0 /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/5.26.0/x86_64-linux /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/5.26.0) at (eval 1) line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 4.
) -- aborting
Setting up doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Can't locate Debian/DocBase/Common.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Debian::DocBase::Common module) (@INC contains: /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0/x86_64-linux /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0 /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/5.26.0/x86_64-linux /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/5.26.0) at /usr/sbin/install-docs line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/install-docs line 8.
```

Some software can be installed successfully, but some can not be.
If I put perl back to the previous, it is normal again. (That must be!)

Module "Debconf::Log" is located at /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/perl5, but I can not find Debian/DocBase/Common.pm. 
Path of /share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/perl5 is inside @INC of perl. Why it can not find it?

I even think that it is the problem when perl installed. I get below error when perl installed: ("make test")

```
Useless use of single ref constructor in void context at op/gv.t line 1191.
In file included from ../../../../perl.h:5644:0,
                 from ExtTest.xs:2:
ExtTest.c: In function ‘XS_ExtTest_constant’:
../../../../embed.h:691:40: warning: ‘pv’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 #define sv_setpvn(a,b,c) Perl_sv_setpvn(aTHX_ a,b,c)
                                        ^
ExtTest.xs:420:14: note: ‘pv’ was declared here
  const char *pv;
              ^
In file included from ../../../../perl.h:5644:0,
                 from ExtTest.xs:2:
../../../../embed.h:691:40: warning: ‘iv’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 #define sv_setpvn(a,b,c) Perl_sv_setpvn(aTHX_ a,b,c)
                                        ^
ExtTest.xs:418:6: note: ‘iv’ was declared here
  IV  iv;
      ^
In file included from ../../../../perl.h:5644:0,
                 from ExtTest.xs:2:
ExtTest.c: In function ‘XS_ExtTest_constant’:
../../../../embed.h:691:40: warning: ‘pv’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 #define sv_setpvn(a,b,c) Perl_sv_setpvn(aTHX_ a,b,c)
                                        ^
ExtTest.xs:194:14: note: ‘pv’ was declared here
  const char *pv;
              ^
In file included from ../../../../perl.h:5644:0,
                 from ExtTest.xs:2:
ExtTest.c: In function ‘XS_ExtTest_constant’:
../../../../embed.h:675:42: warning: ‘iv’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 #define sv_setiv_mg(a,b) Perl_sv_setiv_mg(aTHX_ a,b)
                                          ^
ExtTest.xs:166:6: note: ‘iv’ was declared here
  IV  iv;
      ^
#   Failed test 'cp updated mtime'
#   at t/cp.t line 26.
#     '38'
#         <=
#     '1'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
Request to remove file /share/Software/perl-5.26.0-src/cpan/File-Temp/suffixOEXZVr.dat could not be completed since it is not there!
 at t/mktemp.t line 75.
# parser guessed wrong encoding expected 'CP1252' got 'UTF-8'

#   Failed test 'File 1 atime set correctly'
#   at t/utime.t line 113.
#     '37.684463262558'
#         <
#     '0.1'
#   Failed test 'File 1 mtime set correctly'
#   at t/utime.t line 114.
#     '37.684463262558'
#         <
#     '0.1'
#   Failed test 'File 2 atime set correctly'
#   at t/utime.t line 118.
#     '37.684463262558'
#         <
#     '0.1'
#   Failed test 'File 2 mtime set correctly'
#   at t/utime.t line 119.
#     '37.684463262558'
#         <
#     '0.1'
# Looks like you failed 4 tests of 18.
Can't open copy1-87150: Permission denied at ../lib/File/Copy.t line 326.
# Looks like your test exited with 13 just after 366.
Failed 3 tests out of 2449, 99.88% okay.
### Since not all tests were successful, you may want to run some of
### them individually and examine any diagnostic messages they produce.
### See the INSTALL document's section on "make test".
### You have a good chance to get more information by running
###   ./perl harness
### in the 't' directory since most (>=80%) of the tests succeeded.
### You may have to set your dynamic library search path,
### LD_LIBRARY_PATH, to point to the build directory:
###   setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH `pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd t; ./perl harness
###   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd t; ./perl harness
###   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd t; ./perl harness
### for csh-style shells, like tcsh; or for traditional/modern
### Bourne-style shells, like bash, ksh, and zsh, respectively.
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: What instructions for perl update did you follow?

Comment: You _removed_ your system Perl? Ouch. About half your Ubuntu's core utilities use that Perl. Some of them depend on specific module versions. **Never mess with the system Perl**. If you need a newer Perl in a production environment, compile it and put it somewhere else like you did, and then make the program that should use it aware of it, either via shebang or environment. If you need it locally, look into _plenv_ or [_perlbrew_](https://perlbrew.pl). But never ever mess with the system Perl.

Comment: I would like to replace the perl because some program call /usr/bin/perl, but it needs perl module that is not installed in the system path. And Our system is a computer cluster, I don't want to install perl module in each note. The workload is too big.

Comment: It is too much work to install a module, but it's feasible to compile a new Perl *and* install the module? That is a bit surprising (even more so assuming the cluster is administered via centralized configuration management.) How did you install the software requiring /usr/bin/perl with a specific module – via APT, or manually?

Answer (score 1):

Each Perl is compiled with a few `@INC` directories where it will search for modules. The error message explains which directories are searched:

```
@INC contains:
/share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0/x86_64-linux
/share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0
/share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/5.26.0/x86_64-linux
/share/Software/perl-5.26.0/lib/5.26.0
```

This does not include the directories where APT has installed modules for Perl, e.g. under `/usr/lib`.

However, adding those directories will not help. Some modules are compiled for a specific Perl versions. You cannot upgrade Perl in-place, but would have to reinstall all modules. Since APT contains pre-built modules you cannot use modules installed via APT with a custom Perl.

Therefore: leave the system Perl because Ubuntu depends on its proper functioning. It is safe to install another Perl alongside, e.g. via [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/). It is safe to add a custom Perl to your PATH, e.g. via `perlbrew switch`. This will also fix a couple of additional environment variables that are required for a second Perl to work.

Comment: I have not used perlbrew yet. I should study it later. Is there a way to make different perl use the same module?

Comment: @Susie if you install them in a common directory, then yes. You can also look at local::lib and bring the module with your application.